# Ansible ping to a Windows machine never answers

Tags: linux, windows, ansible

I've got a problem while trying to configure my Ansible server to connect to a Windows host using ssh keys.

When I try this command :

```
ansible win -m win_ping
```

I never got an answer, even after a few minutes. But, when I try to debug using `-vvv`, I don't see any problem in the trace.
So, I tried to copy the ssh command that has been executed, and... it works.

[image: fail with win_ping but works if I copy-paste the command]

Do you know where can the issue be and how to resolve it?

Thanks

I try to connect to a Windows host using Ansible and ssh keys.

The thing I don't understand is why I don't get any answer after my Ansible command. I don't have any error even with -vvv so I'm a bit surprised.

Maybe, if it can help you, when I try to use a playbook, the task stops here and freeze :

[image: command freeze]

I got new information, I've tested from my Ubuntu with Ansible to a Debian and it works like a charm. Do you have any idea why it is just not working with the Windows machine? Maybe I have to change something in the configuration, the path to find Python on Windows, or anything?

Comment: make sure ports 22 and 21 are open on the windows machine's firewall, and that the router/modern has port forwarding for these ports which point to the machine

Comment: Take ansible out the equation. Can you ping the windows host from the host you run ansible. A lot of networks block icmp traffic

Comment: I think i have no problem with ports because i can connect to the machine using basic ssh (with login / password) or using ssh key. Even with copying the command, it works (chack the picture). It's just not working with the ansible ping command. And yes Chris, I can ping from Ansible server to the Windows VM

Comment: Ansible ping module is not ICMP ping. Do you have all prerequisites installed on your windows target? Check the documentation.

Comment: @Zeitounator I didn't realise that it wasn't icmp under the module. Great shout

Comment: @Zeitounator Yep, it's what I thought. On my target, I've installed Python 3.7 which is a requirements, an OpenSSH server and I put the public key of my Ansible server to connect without password. I am a beginner so maybe I've missed something despite having read the documentation. If you have any idea or tips, I'll take it.

Comment: As far as requirements are concerned, Python should also be installed on the target nodes, but that's it for those.

Comment: It's exactly what I did, I have python 3.9 and Ansible 2.14 on my control node, and Python 3.7 on my target node. I really don't understand why it's not working... SSH is working, Ansible and Python installed but I can't set up a connection

Comment: I updated the post with new infos, maybe it will give someone the answer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That said, things like `'User="Administrator"'` look like double quoting to me and may not behave as intended. Also, that log output, what shell does it run through, both in cases it works and in cases it doesn't? BTW: You can instruct SSH to emit lots of debugging info concerning connection, key exchange, authentication etc.

Comment: RESOLUTION
The problem was the shell type. I don't know why but I had "ansible_shell_executable=cmd" instead of "ansible_shell_type=cmd" (probably due to hours of trying to debug and seeing random things on the internet). And personnally, Powershell doesn't work, look the comment of jborean93 here : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/67143#issuecomment-587931523
It semmes to be normal, we have to use the default prompt we get when we SSH to the machine.